# On GITHUB, how to achieve auto-merging commits from old to latest version branches?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In a GITHUB repository,Lets consider I have the following branches :-

```
  |---> version-1.0
  |
  |---> version-2.0
  |
  |---> version-2.1
  |
  |---> version-3.0
  |
  V
 master
```

When I commit something on branch "version-1.0" OR create a new branch "version-1.1" from branch "version-1.0" and start committing, I need those commits to merge automatically to the following branches :-

```
version-2.0
version-2.1
version-3.0 and
master
```

What I need is, all commits to the older version branches should be automatically merged to all the later version branches as well as master.

I particularly need this feature for handling a special group of customers of our company and I am stuck in this. Any idea of how to achieve it ?

Comment: You have problems in getting this done automatically or you don't know how to merge them?

Comment: I can find means to merge them . But I need those merges to be done automatically.

Comment: For example, if you committed in `version-1.0`, you have to `git checkout version-2.0.0 && git merge version-1.0` (same for the other branches). Of course, this can be automated. Does this merge command work for you?

Comment: Yeah. This merge command works for me @Ionică Bizău. I am setting up the version control system and automating this command needs to be done on server-side, since we prefer not to impose each and every developer to run the script. Is that possible ?

Comment: I may invest time in writing a little too to do what you describe. Should be simple. Hope you will consider then marking my answer as correct (looks like this is your first question here).

Comment: Like I said before, I need that automating script to run on the server-side ie, whenever any developer commits to any branch, the script should check for all future branches and merge the commits to all of them. Is that possible @Ionică Bizău?

Comment: I don't think so–there could appear conflicts that should be reviewed by a human.

Comment: Yes. Merge conflicts may occur. But we have big development teams that deal with different parts and versions of our software. When a version of a software gets some change, it should be reflected in all its future versions. If at all merge conflict occurs (which is rare in our case), then we will resolve it manually. But till the conflict, the auto-merge feature should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research on the above, I have found that Bitbucket Server, a product of Atlassian, has the in-built fuctionality to achieve auto-merge on release branches.

For more details, refer [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html).